# Combination of editable and readonly rows in TreeTable

Tags: vaadin

I want to make some rows and not all as read-only based on some flags in tree table. Is this possible? Could anyone tell me how to achieve this?

Regards,
Azhar

Answer (score 2):

There is a good chapter regarding Vaadin data model - [Binding Components to Data](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/datamodel.html)
Frankly speaking it is enough to analyze two images:

[image]

[image]

Property is the key.

> The Property interface is the base of the Vaadin Data Model. It
>   provides a standardized API for a single data value object that can be
>   read (get) and written (set). A property is always typed, but can
>   optionally support data type conversions.

And also read this:

> The most important function of the Property as well as of the other
>   data model interfaces is to connect classes implementing the interface
>   directly to editor and viewer classes. This means connecting a data
>   source (model) to a user interface component (views) to allow editing
>   or viewing the data model.

[Property](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/Property.html) interface defines everything you need

[image]

So look through the chapter and you'll find everything you need.